# Code flow of "SIP protocol invocation followed by RTP packets flow" after callingACTION_CALL

Tags: android, telephony

I am newbee in android. I was going through Android telephony architecture and I have a following question.
When application calls android API with ACTION_CALL intent, then it goes through RIL for establishing session (using SIP assume) and for sending/receiving RTP packets.
Can someone brief me a source code flow (along with function call) of how and when SIP is getting called and when SIP connection is established, how and when RTP is getting called (via RIL). Even one side call flow or even one call flow will help.

Many thanks in advance... Any small pointer will also help.
Thanks
-Nagendra

Answer (score 0):

What I could found that the path of signal/data flow during "1. Android telephony (typical carrier based like Vodafone, Airtel, etc)" and "2. SIP based VOIP calls" are different.

1. Android telephony: By design Android smart phones have two processors. One for Java and native code and another for running vendor specific code i.e. base band processor. All the signals are passed via socket between RIL Layer(Sender and Receiver i.e. Java and Jni code) and RILD/'Vendor Specific Library'. So, all the communication details are in folder hardware/ril*.
   When connections(signaling) are established, Java API gets either Ringing or Connection Established callback via socket from Vendor Specific library. Even the connection establishment happens with VSL(Vendor Specific Library). So, we can't have any reach of source code.
2. SIP based VOIP calls: This is application level protocol and it only needs Internet connection. You can use any open source SIP implementation (PJSIP, MJSIP, etc) and link with the API of the SIP protocol and write your own Calling App. In this way, you have full control of source code including SIP. The code flow of signals and data is the same and that is via Internet(via UDP, Socket).